# PhoneGap: How do I prevent the Center of a 9-Patch File to be streached?

Tags: java, android, cordova, nine-patch

Using PhoneGap/Cordova I want to use 9-patch image to build a PhoneGap Splash Screen with a Logo in the center of the screen. When using the [draw9patch][1] tool the center element which is the logo gets squeezed when the display is big.

I found a similar question here: [9 Patch image where center is 1:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791636/9-patch-image-where-center-is-11) but this question does not answer how to solve this problem with an Android PhoneGap app.

**How can I create a Splash screen with a centered logo for a PhoneGap Android app?**

Comment: The black bars along the edges can have breaks in them.  I'm pretty sure this is explained in the official 9patch docs, but if you're too lazy to Google it, then so am I.

Comment: In the link you found, this answer is the one you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19791748/2258795

Comment: @BrodoFraggins I did not understand what to do. Can you please explain it. The image should always be in the center.

Comment: Posted an answer with an image.  BTW, sorry for my snark.  I usually hate everyone by the end of a day at the office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crude drawing showing how the "stretch" bars of a 9patch image can be split if you have something in the middle like your logo or the edge of a rendered reflection or anything else that you want to remain sharp and undistorted.

[image: crude drawing of 9patch]